# Kendo Dropdownlist with checkbox and keyboard navigation

Tags: kendo-ui

I am newbie in the Kendo UI in Jquery and looking Kendo dropdown list with checkbox selection,"Select All" option and keyboard navigation.

Luckily, I found example on google but it doesnt work in my version "Kendo UI v2018.1.221" and Jquery version "1.12.4"

```
Link :http://jsfiddle.net/b6ow4d2j/1/
```

If anybody have solution pleas help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Kendo there is a new widget called [DropDownTree](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdowntree/checkboxes) that can work the same way if you only populate it with root items and set tagMode: "single". Here is a working [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/ekUjokiG).

Comment: Plamen : Thank you so much for this suggestion but I had fulfill my requirement with multiselection control in last week. However, your answer is acceptable.

Comment: Today i changed kendo version but require validation doesn't work on DropDownTree. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: The exact scenario is not quite clear so I would recommend you to elaborate it in [KendoForums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui).